# Music application able to play by directory?

Tags: 8.1, apps, music

I am searching for an app which can play music in given directory. Can you recommend me one? I have preference on free applications, but I am able to pay if I need to. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend Loco Music Player. It's really fast, fluid and it does let you pick specific folders to play the music from. It's $1.49, but it's absolutely worth it. Check out the reviews and give it a try. Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/loco-music-player/9wzdncrfjh3b